# Spawning an interactive process

Tags: java, scala, process, spawn

How can a Java application spawn a new interactive application (e.g. an command line editor) from Java/Scala?

When I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vim test")`, I would only get a Process instance, while `vim` would be running in the background; rather then appear to the user.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to wrap input and output writers using [`System.console()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

You will have to manually redirect every input to the spawned process and every output to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on linux you actually have to run the command in new terminal window

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"xterm", "-e", "vim test"});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to run the app on the same terminal.

Comment: That presumes your Java code has a controlling terminal and the standard bindings of descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

MMmmm. Try this:

```
scala.sys.Process("vim test").run(true)
```

Oops, that's only on the Scala trunk -- possibly Scala 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You should **only** use this method when you absolutely need to have a terminal/console such as what vim requires.  For all other uses, go with Runtime.exec().

I've just had this same problem.  What I've gotten to work is using Java Native Interface to call into a small c function that does a system call:

SystemProcess.java:

```
class SystemProcess {
  public native int systemCall(String cmd);
  public boolean execute() { return systemCall("vim test") == 0; }
  static { System.loadLibrary("SystemProcess"); }
}
```

SystemProcess.c

```
#include [javah-generated-header.h]
[javah-generated-function-prototype] (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jcmd) {
  jboolean iscopy;
  const char *cmd = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jcmd, &iscopy);
  jint ec = system(cmd);
  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jcmd, cmd);
  return ec;
}
```

I'll leave it up to you how to actually do all the header generation and c compilation to shared library.  Feel free to replace system with fork/exec or posix_spawn if it makes you feel better.  But for the most part, this should work as-is on unix/linux.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.7 this is quite straight forward. (Of course, everything is when you have solved it before)

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/vim");
Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();
builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
final Process process = builder.start();
process.waitFor();
```